# How to use "of which" to refer to a percentage

Tags: grammar

Please help me with the use "*of which*" in the following context:

Original sentence:

> A and B caused the problem for 50% and 23% of the elderly people in
>   England respectively.

Rewrite (option 1):

> A and B cause the problem for almost three quarters (73%) of the
>   elderly people in England, of which 50% being affected by A and 23%
>   being a result of B.

Rewrite (option 2):

> A and B cause the problem for almost three quarters (73%) of the
>   elderly people in England, of which around two thirds being affected
>   by A and a third being a result of B.

Also, I'm not so sure whether "of which" in this case refers to "*almost three quarters (73%) of the elderly people in England*", or it refers to *England only*.

Comment: I think it's correctly used here.  
Here, "of which" refers to the clause "three quarters (73%) of the elderly people in England".

Comment: If you think it's ambiguous, then just be more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the biggest difference between your two options, which virmaior doesn't seem to have considered (or at least didn't mention) is what the percentages add up to. Let's make the numbers smaller, so it's more noticeable:

> Every day, up to 12% of British people accidentally punch themselves in the face, of which 9% use their right hand, and 3% use their left hand.

versus:

> Every day, up to 12% of British people accidentally punch themselves in the face, of which 75% use their right hand, and 25% use their left hand.

Should the percentages in the "of which" part add up to the previous 12%, or add up to 100%. Convention seems to be that they should add up to 100%; i.e. the latter option.

Also, when referring to people you should probably use "of whom" rather than "of which". It's one of the few uses of "whom" where you're unlikely to get accused of being pretentious!

Answer (score -1):

I would go with the following:

> A and B cause the problem for almost three quarters (73%) of the elderly people in England, of which 50% are affected by A and 23% of cases are a result of B.

This is different from your option A in that I am preferring the construction that makes both of the sections that follow *of which* into subordinate clauses with verbs in normal conjugation rather than "being" clauses.